# could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.windowsazure.storage.emulator.controller

Tags: c#, azure

(I'm working with Azure SDK 2.2)

When I open Server Explorer - Azure - Storage - Development it gives me the following error
"could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.windowsazure.storage.emulator.controller...'"

Everything else works perfectly. What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: any updates for this? I met the same issue.... SOS

Comment: i ended up NOT USING the server explorer from VS, and had to wait until we upgraded the azure SDK, so no help from me.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I removed runtime references from web.config  and worked for me on production server !